# How to copy file from Windows to Linux machine through command line?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, scp

I am trying to copy a file which is present in my local machine - which is Windows 10.
And I have connected to Linux server from my PC through VNCViewer.

Now I need to write a shell script on my server to copy file from my windows machine to that linux server.
So I am using *scp* command to do this.

> scp *username*@*ip_addr*:/Users/*username*/eclipse-workspace/project/file.c
>   /root/*username*/some_folder_path/

But when i try to do this, I get the error like-

> ssh: connect to host *ip_addr* port 22: Connection refused

I guess SSH is not running on the windows, that would be the reason for this error.

Is this the write way to do it or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Open a windows terminal and connect to your linux server with sftp

```
sftp username@linuxIP
```

then you can browse inside your linux server using commands `cd` `ls` etc. From that terminal you can also use `lcd` `lls` to move (or show files) inside your local machine (windows 10 in your case). You can get files by typing `get <filename>` and send items with `put <filename>`

Comment: My intension is to write a script on the server side. So I need to be executing the command from Linux server and not from windows machine